# Cookies are not sent on HTTP GET

Tags: google-chrome, http, cookies

I am using HTTP Only (and secure in production) cookies to maintain a users authentication state with a backend API.

I've run into an issue however where the Cookies are NOT being sent on HTTP GET requests. POST and PATCH requests work perfectly, but gets are missing the Cookies request headers.

I've seen nothing about this being a specific limitation as part of the standards. The Mozilla documentation explicitly has an example with a GET request including Cookies?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

As context I am currently in development and so running on "localhost" and using Chrome 63.0.3239.132.

**Edit**: Added images

So cookies are set in the application

[image: Cookies Set]

PATCH request sends the Cookies as expected

[image: Patch Working, sending cookies as expected]

GET request includes nothing. I threw the 404 because I could not find the cookie values.

[image: Get Not Working, no cookies are sent]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was with the javascript (actually Typescript) code making the AJAX request using JQuery.

Cookies are considered credentials and therefore the XHR request must allow `withCredentials=true`.

```js
let ajax = this.jQuery.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: getUrl,
  headers: this.generateHeaders(),
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true // this was false.
  },
  timeout: this.options.RequestTimeoutMs
});
```

After changing the `withCredentials` field cookies were sent!

**Side Note**: on `withCredentials`. You will require CORS settings to allow this, specifically `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true` at which point you cannot use `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` (not a good idea anyway) but instead will have to specify domains with no trailing `/'s`